# Display unpurchased products on WooCommerce My account custom section

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, endpoint

I have added a custom endpoint "recommended books" to my account. Using a shortcode, I displayed a list of products. I want to hide the products that the user has already purchased. But all my attempts don't work...

```
// That's how I added the Recommended books endpoint to my account
 add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'recommended_books_link', 25 );
 function recommended_books_link( $menu_links ){

$menu_links = array_slice( $menu_links, 0, 1, true ) + array( 'recommended-books' => 'Recommended books' ) + 
array_slice( $menu_links, 1, NULL, true );
return $menu_links;

 }

add_action( 'init', 'you_add_endpoints', 25 );
  function you_add_endpoints() {

add_rewrite_endpoint( 'recommended-books', EP_PAGES );

  }

add_action( 'woocommerce_account_recommended-books_endpoint', 'you_contents', 25 );
function you_contents() {
echo '<div class="sav" style= "margin-bottom: 25px;" > <h1>Recommended books_link</h1> 
</div>';
echo do_shortcode('[products limit="10" columns="1" paginate="true"]');

 }
```

Here is this code that I use to hide the products purchased by users. But it doesn't work...

```
 //Hide product
 add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hide_product_from_shop_page_if_user_already_purchased', 20);

      function hide_product_from_shop_page_if_user_already_purchased( $query ) {

        if ( ! $query->is_main_query() ) return;

          if ( ! is_admin()  && is_page() && is_shop()) {

           $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
            if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) return;
   
        $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => $current_user->ID,
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
        'post_status' => array( 'wc-processing', 'wc-completed' ),
    ) );
   
    if ( ! $customer_orders ) return;
    
    $product_ids = array();
    
    foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order->ID );
        if( $order ){
            $items = $order->get_items();
            foreach ( $items as $item ) {
                $product_id    = $item->get_product_id();
                $product_ids[] = $product_id;
            }
        }
    }

    $product_ids = array_unique( $product_ids );

    $query->set( 'post__not_in', $product_ids );
   }

}
```

Comment: @Slbox This is the right place for WooCommerce tagged questions as **all related WP plugin questions are off-topic in WordPress StackExchange**… So please remove your comment.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I initially was inclined to agree based on the sidebar, but I think that's a misinterpretation of it. [Plugins](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/plugins/info) is the most common tag on the site and I think this question is related to programming, not a mere support question. If you can show me my misunderstanding I'll happily delete.

Comment: @Slbox When doing that with new users (or with low rep users), they think that they are not asking in the right place, and they get confused. WooCommerce related questions are off-topic in WordPress StackExchange (see the tag [woocommerce](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce) in WordPress StackExchange). so yes please could you remove your comment.

Comment: I'm not fully sold given that those questions do not actually appear to be closed, unanswered, or downvoted, but will defer given your reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to exclude products with `post__not_in` in from a product query in WooCommerce shortcode `[products]` via `woocommerce_shortcode_products_query` dedicated hook.

So What I have done is that I have get all product IDS excluding the customer purchased products and inserted that in the shortcode using `ids` argument:

```php
// Utiility function: Get all unpurchased product Ids
function get_unpurchased_products_ids( $current_user ) {
    // Get Customer orders
    $customer_orders = wc_get_orders( array(
        'limit'         => -1,
        'customer'      => $current_user->ID,
        'status'        => wc_get_is_paid_statuses(),
    ) );

    $customer_product_ids = array(); // Initializing

    if ( count($customer_orders) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
            $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order->get_id() );

            foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
                $customer_product_ids[] = $item->get_product_id();
            }
        }
    }
    // Get all unpurchased product ids
    $product_ids  = wc_get_products( array(
        'status'  => 'publish',
        'limit'   => -1,
        'exclude' => array_unique($customer_product_ids),
        'return'  => 'ids',
    ) );
    // return a coma separated string of unpurchased product Ids
    return implode(',', $product_ids);
}

// That's how I added the Recommended books endpoint to my account
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'recommended_books_link', 25 );
function recommended_books_link( $menu_links ){
    $menu_links = array_slice( $menu_links, 0, 1, true ) + array( 'recommended-books' => 'Recommended books' ) + 
    array_slice( $menu_links, 1, NULL, true );
    return $menu_links;
}

add_action( 'init', 'you_add_endpoints', 25 );
function you_add_endpoints() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'recommended-books', EP_PAGES );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_account_recommended-books_endpoint', 'recommended_book_endpoint_content', 25 );
function recommended_book_endpoint_content() {
    global $current_user;

    echo '<div class="sav" style= "margin-bottom: 25px;">
        <h1>Recommended books_link</h1>
    </div>';

    $product_ids = get_unpurchased_products_ids( $current_user );   

    echo do_shortcode("[products limit='20' columns='1' paginate='true' ids='{$product_ids}']");
}
```

Tested and works.

---

Addition:

To exclude some product Ids, replace:

```php
                $customer_product_ids[] = $item->get_product_id();
```

with:

```php
                if ( ! in_array( $item->get_product_id(), array(18, 24) ) ) {
                    $customer_product_ids[] = $item->get_product_id();
                }
```

Where product Ids 18 and 24 will be displayed even if purchased...

Comment: LogicTheAztec, can you help me with one more question? How in your response can I exclude from the check a product with ID 18? So that customers can buy it without restriction?

Comment: I have added an addition, so you will use `array(18)` instead of `array(18, 24)`

Comment: LoicTheAztec, this worked, thank you.